# Should decltype(1, t) be an l-value reference? (Compilers disagree)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, decltype

Minimal code:

```
int t;
static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(1, t), int&>);
```

The above compiles in g++ and clang++ but fails in MSVC. MSVC seems to think:

```
int t;
static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(1, t), int>);
```

Which one does the standard specify? I rely on this pattern quite a bit for SFINAE.

Comment: I guess MSVC resolves the comma operator and then processes `decltype(t)` instead of `decltype((t))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc and Clang are correct. `1, t` is [comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator),

> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, `E2`.

The 2nd operand, i.e. `t` is an lvalue, then [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) would result in `T&`.

> If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>
> - if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;

From the standard, [[expr.comma]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#1):

(emphasis mine)

> The type and value of the result are the type and value of the right
>   operand; **the result is of the same value category as its right
>   operand**,

and [[dcl.type.decltype]/1.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.5)

> otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type
>   of `e`;

BTW: I tried with MSVC [here](https://rextester.com/JHAJ85786) and got the same result with Gcc and Clang.

Comment: The link you gave deduced to int tho which is different from int& from gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/DWbDoV

Comment: @NarutSereewattanawoot It seems MSVC behaving differently in different version; anyway the correct deduced type should be `int&`.